# scenebuilder 8.3.0 disappearing menus and no resize

Tags: scenebuilder, gluon

I tried SceneBuilder 8.3.0 (executable jar) on a RHEL 6.3 but I fail to get it run properly.

First, I get undesired logs on the sceen. Then, closing the splash screen a java.net.UnknownHostException is displayed.

Then the main window cannot be resized. And, when I click on the main bar menu item, the popup menu opens then disappears immediately. When I click on the very top of the menu item - outside the popup menu display - is correctly displayed.

Note that I have no issue of that kind with JavaFX on the same machine.

How to get SceneBuilder work properly?

Comment: Am I the only one to have this issue with SceneBuilder 8.3.0?

Comment: Isn't this forum the one to get official Gluon support?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with ubuntu 17.04 and gnome 3.

Cant resize window and no menu works. We click, they apear and disapear when we release the mouse button.

**HOWEVER,I only have this problem when launching scenebuilder directly.**

If called from eclipse, (after installing e(fx)clipse),or from NetBeans scenbuilder opens the fxml file and works properly.

If Scene Builder does not open in eclipse, go to Window | Preferences | JavaFX and set the correct path to your Scene Builder installation.

Then, right click in the fxml file and you should find an option to "open with Scenebuilder".

Hope this works for you.

EDITED ********* in SceneBuilder 8.4.0 the problematic behaviour seems to have disapeared.

Answer (score -1):

From Experience: If you provide your email to get registered, you will not get this issue. This may be a Gluon Policy. Hope this helps somebody facing same issue.